# Copy from local Hadoop cluster to remote network share

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, nfs, smb, distcp

How do i copy from local hadoop cluster to a remote NFS or SMB share using Hadoop distcp ? i see the options copy to another cluster, local directory, amazon and azure blobs

Comment: You could NFS mount a volume locally, then use hdfs get or getmerge commands

Comment: Yes this is doable, but the machine mounting this NFS will be a the bottleneck as all traffic has to go through it, wanted to see if we can instruct the distcp to point to NFS/SMB directly so the cluster data nodes communicate with it directly.

Comment: I believe NFS protocol doesn't have any type of load balancing itself. So won't the NFS server already be the bottleneck?

Comment: Also, you need to collect all remote HDFS blocks into a single file before it can be uploaded to NFS anyway

Comment: Is there a command to copy a file from hadoop edge node to windows shared drive path ? Can we use smb for that